# Joins inside a Trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers

I am trying to create a Trigger, that will update the History Table with Receipt Information.

My Source Table has a SourceID and a ReceiptID.

So when i Update Receipt table, i want to copy that record to the history table, but i first need to get the SourceID of the source that is being updated.

this is what i have now:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_ReceiptHistory] 
ON [dbo].[tblReceipt]
for UPDATE
AS 
begin try
INSERT INTO tblHistorySource(RecShipName, RecShipAddress, sourceID)
select t1.shippingName, t1.shippingAddress, t2.sourceID
from [DELETED] t1, tblSource t2
where t2.receiptID = t1.receiptID
end try
begin catch
SELECT
ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
RAISERROR('Error in Source Hisotry Trigger' ,16,1)
ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

when i try to do a simple update to the tblReceipt, i get the following error:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trg_ReceiptHistory, Line 24
Error in Source Hisotry Trigger
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Am I doing it wrong? please help :(

Comment: What are the details on the error that sends you into the `catch` block in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is remove the CATCH, to see the error. We can go from there.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_ReceiptHistory] 
ON [dbo].[tblReceipt]
for UPDATE
AS 
--begin try
INSERT INTO tblHistorySource(RecShipName, RecShipAddress, sourceID)
select t1.shippingName, t1.shippingAddress, t2.sourceID
from [DELETED] t1, tblSource t2
where t2.receiptID = t1.receiptID
/*end try
begin catch
SELECT
ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
RAISERROR('Error in Source Hisotry Trigger' ,16,1)
ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH*/
```